# how to install daemontools (supervise) on centos 5?

Tags: process, centos5, daemontools

I'd like to use supervise to monitor httpd, mysqld and hudson processes on Centos 5. When any of these processes go down I'd like to use a tool to automatically restart them.

I've read and heard about supervise, but couldn't find a way to install it on centos.

Can anyone help me with that? Any other tools are also good, as long as they can be easily installed on centos 5 and allow me to automatically restart httpd, mysqld, hudson.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You mean like `init`?

Comment: I don't know. Does init support auto-restarting crashed services? If yes, please share how?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can be worth to try out [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/)

It is compatible with daemontools and has rpm packages available.
The install instructions are http://smarden.org/runit/install.html (if you compile from source instead)

You can stick to daemontools if you want http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/install.html

Tell the error messages if you get stuck with the install process.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to consider monit, it automatically restarts stopped services.

http://mmonit.com/monit/

http://www.howtoforge.com/server_monitoring_monit_munin